# Files.isSameFile in Java 7

Tags: java, file

I am trying to do file protect by making two same files and later using 
Files.isSameFile to check if one of them was edited. Here is my code that is not working.

```
                Path path = Paths.get("zapis.lnk");
                Path path2 = Paths.get("C:/zapis.lnk");

                if (Files.isSameFile(path, path2)){
                    System.out.println("It is a copy");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("It's not a copy");
                }
```

At this moment i've copied zapis.lnk using windows explorer to C: but after i try run my app it says "It's not a copy". What code should i use to check it?

Comment: If you copied the file and are not running the code from `C:\\ `, then the paths are different, so they shouldn't be the same. You should try reading the byte content of the files and compare that

Answer (score 1):

Two distinct physical files cannot by definition be the same file, even if these have exactly the same content. 
And as stated by the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-), `Files.isSameFile()` test whether :

> two paths locate the same file.

`Files.isSameFile()` returns `true` only if the `Path`s refers the same file such as :

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/folder/zapis.lnk");
Path path2 = Paths.get("C:/folder").resolve("zapis.lnk"); 
Files.isSameFile(path, path2); // return true
```

For your requirement you need to compare bytes of the two files and in order to perform things in an optimized way you should first compare the file length before comparing their bytes.
You could use a robust third library that does that for you.

For example : [`FileUtils.contentEquals()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#contentEquals(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) that is specified like :

> Compares the contents of two files to determine if they are equal or
>   not. This method checks to see if the two files are different lengths
>   or if they point to the same file, before resorting to byte-by-byte
>   comparison of the contents.

So you could do :

```
boolean isContentEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(path.toFile(), path2.toFile());
```